# How to create a table in SQL phpMyAdmin 3.11

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a table with these details

```
CREATE TABLE site_data
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(250),
    link VARCHAR(250),
    description TEXT
);
```

but there is another field as shown below

I am new to SQL and PHP.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NoRHz.jpg]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Wow, people actually still use Yahoo Messenger? I'm astonished... anyway; you have to define a default value for any field that is `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Return to home. Click the database in which you want to add the table. Click "SQL" at the top, then copy and paste your code into the run SQL area. Hit Go, and your table should have been created. Make sure its within a database.